# How does a complex number represents some thing....

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I saw in a movie that let "Z" be a complex number and $|Z|=1$ represents a Circle with center at the origin.. I have no knowledge about it and have no idea how to do it,, so if I could get a bit help,, i know everyone here is ready to help...... Thanks in advance...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane.

Comment: @IHF,, it Didnt helped....

Answer (score 0):

A circle in $\Bbb R^2$ is described as the set of points $(x,y)$ such that
$$x^2+y^2=1$$
In complex numbers we write numbers $a+bi\in\Bbb C$ which can be viewed as a two dimensional vector like $\Bbb R^2$, the differens lies in that normally $\Bbb R^2$ is not viewed as having any form of multiplication, but $\Bbb C$ does have multiplication, a very specific one. Either way from that we have a norm $|a+bi|^2=a^2+b^2$, so when we write 
$$|z|=|a+bi|=1$$
we mean that
$$a^2+b^2=1$$
do you see the similarity to the previous equation now?